# Tablerow textview above edittext (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, scrollview, tablelayout

I hope you can help. So what i need to do is to have edittext below textview (Very well explained in the picture)

(Picture)
[image: http://www.upload.ee/image/4134038/Untitled.png]

Code:

```
for(int x=0 ; x < loopCount; x++){
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams( headerCellsWidth[x+1],LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //left? up? right? down?

        TextView tv1=new TextView(getContext());
        EditText et1=new EditText(getContext());


        et1.setHeight(40);
        et1.setWidth(40);

        tv1.setText("Text");




        TextView textViewB = this.bodyTextView(info[x]);
        taleRowForTableD.addView(tv1,params);
        taleRowForTableD.addView(et1);

    }
```

I hope you can help me out :) 
Here is full example http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keeping your `EditText` and `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout`, and then put that `RelativeLayout` in `TableRow`'s cell.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("My text");

EditText et = new EditText(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv.getId());

layout.addView(tv);        
layout.addView(et, lp);
taleRowForTableD.addView(layout);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If i want to ask another question about adding something. Should i make new question or ask it here?
Thank you, i'm a newbie :(

Comment: @user3793563 If its related to this layout, and a small thing, ask in comment, else post new question.

Comment: Okey, ill post a new one. It's the same problem, but not the same code